# Javascript to VB.Net [FEW LINES]

Tags: javascript, .net, vb.net

I am trying to find out what this "POST" request does, and translate the code into vb.net, for a webrequest. Will comment what I know already

```
var xmlhttp; //Defining the "xmlhttp" variable
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest() 
    } else {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() { //If the xmlhttp is created then do this:
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) { //Don't know
            fired = true; //The function gathered the conditions to start
            var title = '<div id="message_box_title_unavailable">woops!</div>'; //Doesn't matter
            var result; //Variable "result"
            if (xmlhttp.responseText == 'available') { //If the xml file contains "available" on it then do this, else return an error...
                result = 'The name you selected <strong>' + user + 'is available!'
            } else {
                result = 'There was an error processing your request.  Please try again.'
            }
        }
    };
    xmlhttp.open("POST", "Checkusername.php", true); //Didn't I translate this correctly?
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"); //What am I missing from this line in my vb code?
    xmlhttp.send("name=" + name + "&n=" + Math.random()) //The same...
}
```

Alright - My Vb translation

```vb
Dim req As HttpWebRequest
Dim res As HttpWebResponse
Dim cookies As New CookieContainer()
req = WebRequest.Create("http://blablabla.net/Checkusername.php?name=" & name "&n=" R.Next(0, 20000))
req.Method = "POST"
req.ContentType = "application/xml"
req.Headers.Add("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
req.CookieContainer = cookies
res = req.GetResponse
Dim webStream As Stream
webStream = res.GetResponseStream
Dim reader As New StreamReader(webStream)
checksource.text = reader.readtoend
```

This always returns me an "error" instead of the desired result, which is always correct in HTML

Basically, I can't translate line 3/5 and the 3 last ones.

Thanks for helping guys!

Comment: Please share the entire error message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you do a GET, you supply params in the url. When you do a POST, you supply them in the request. Also, not sure why you're creating a cookies object if you're not using it.

You don't need:

```
Dim res As HttpWebResponse
Dim cookies As New CookieContainer()
```

Try this:

```
'Create the post string which contains the params
Dim postString As String = "name=" & name & "&n=" & R.Next(0, 20000)

'Create the request
req = WebRequest.Create("http://blablabla.net/Checkusername.php")
req.Method = "POST"
req.ContentLength = postString.Length
req.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

'put the POST params in the request
Dim requestWriter As StreamWriter = New StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream())
requestWriter.Write(postString)
requestWriter.Close()

'submit the request and read the response
Dim responseReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream())
Dim responseData As String = responseReader.ReadToEnd()

'close everything
responseReader.Close()
req.GetResponse().Close()
```

**responseData** will contain your response string

You can also surround it with a Try/Catch to check for any exceptions...bad internet connection, bad url, no response, etc. `xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200` in the html means `request finished` and `OK`